# where is my error(probably trivial)? (analysis/continuity question)

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals, continuity

Let $f: [-1,2] \rightarrow R$ be a continuous function and define the sequence $$f_n(x)=(n/2)\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n} f(t)dt$$ I want to prove that $f_n$ is continuous.
Let $$|x-x_1|<\delta$$. We have that $$|f_n(x)-f_n(x_1)|=|(n/2)\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n} f(t)dt-(n/2)\int_{x_1-1/n}^{x_1+1/n} f(t)dt|$$ and as $f$ is continuous on $[-1,2]$ and therefore limited, lets say limited by $M>0$.
So $$|f_n(x)-f_n(x_1)|=|(n/2)\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n} f(t)dt-(n/2)\int_{x_1-1/n}^{x_1+1/n} f(t)dt|\leq |(n/2)\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n} M dt-(n/2)\int_{x_1-1/n}^{x_1+1/n} M dt|=| M-M|=0 <\epsilon$$. With a few more steps i would get the required result, if this was correct, which i dont think it its because i didn't use the condition on $|x-x_1|<\delta$ and then for all $x,x_1 \in [0,1]$ we would get $|f_n(x)-f_n(x_1)|=0$. Can anyone point my error? I think it is a trivial one, but i cant find

Comment: You cannot have $$\left|\int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^{x+\frac{1}{n}}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t-\int_{x_1-\frac{1}{n}}^{x_1+\frac{1}{n}}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right|\stackrel{?}\leq\left|\int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^{x+\frac{1}{n}}M\,\mathrm{d}t-\int_{x_1-\frac{1}{n}}^{x_1+\frac{1}{n}}M\,\mathrm{d}t\right|$$ in general. This does not follow from any of the basic properties of integral and/or absolute value, and is false in general. (For instance, consider the example $f(x)=x$ so that $f_n(x)=x$ for all $n$.)

Comment: oh, i see, i confused with another props;
in fact was a trivial error,
thanks very much

Comment: No worries! Trivial errors are sometimes the hardest errors to notice.